# stop SwipeRefreshLayout trigger programmatically

Tags: android, material-design, swiperefreshlayout

I have researched how to start the Android SwipeRefreshLayout programmatically. 
I have found that [website](http://codetube.xyz/swiperefreshlayout-trigger-programmatically-1014/) where it is explained how to do that.

Here is the code how I start the animation:

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            }
        });
```

BNow I would like to stop the animation of the SwipeRefreshLayout when the data is loaded.

The code

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
```

does not work for me.

Has anyone an idea ?

Comment: Are you calling both of the `setRefreshing(bool)` methods on the same instance of your swipe refresh layout? The code you have written is correct to stop the swipe refresh.

Comment: I have got a global variable called mSwipeRefreshLayout. So I think it should be the same instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);` does not appear to trigger the `onRefresh()` listener. It only shows the animation. I'm assuming you are calling `mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);` as a result of something that happens in your refresh handler.

The solution is to call your refresh method manually from within the `Runnable`.

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        myRefreshMethod();
    }
});
```